# Google drive and authorized HTTP GET for downloading a file

Tags: google-drive-api

I develop application for Google Drive. I have problem with downloading files. Official doc describes this process with next words: "To download a file's content, send an authorized HTTP GET request to the file's downloadUrl.". The main problem is in "authorized HTTP GET request". I've used:

- login:password@downloadUrl
- downloadUrl&access_token={my_token}
- downloadUrl&access_key={my_token}
- downloadUrl&key={my_token}

And none of these have helped me. If I try to download file it opens browser for authorization in the very first time. 
Can you help me download file without usermade authorization?

Answer (score 2):

To download the file's content, you will need to use an OAuth 2.0 access token in an authorized HTTP request such as:

```
GET <dowloadUrl>
Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

You can try this with `curl` by using a command such as:

```
curl <downloadUrl> -H 'Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>'
```

If you want to be able to download the file from a web browser using cookie authentication (using the cookies of the currently logged-in user), you should use the `webContentLink` instead.

Comment: You can have more verbose information by using the `'-v` flag: `curl -v <downloadUrl> -H 'Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>'`