# Downloading files from google drive with rest API / c++

Tags: rest, google-drive-api

I have files in my google drive , very small ones, <10kB, and I try to download those by using  downloadUrl , but the result only seems to be redirection to happen all the time. I have seen also discussions  about that but no actual results ..

I am using c++ and creating rest API request by myself ( not using any libraries for this )

But also , when I copy the url I receive after continue="..." web browser can make a download okay but calling that from C++ seems to cause just another redirection to happen .

I followed the instructions from:
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads

Comment: You're setting a valid access token in the GET request?

Comment: Yeps. But in the response I only get redirection url in response . and  from there I pick the url after continue="http://www.redirectheresample.com?access_token="<valid_token>" and run the new get request but then the similar redirection happens again ..

Comment: What is it redirecting to? and plse confirm which File property URL you are using to download

Comment: I am using download url as a file property . weird thing is that if I copy the url from continue="" and paste it to e.g Chrome address line, file get's downloaded

Comment: can you paste what you are seeing in downloadUrl

Comment: Yes, sorry for the break, looks like this: downloadUrl: https://doc-0c-0c-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/1fmljejnttld46hptqmuso8k4rlm6qsb/lt4jbfh1e5lv15r4fcnori3irgcth58i/1391407200000/04657620415318185245/04657620415318185245/0B1qK40ylyoUCRVNzV2pvbXNtSGs?h=16653014193614665626&e=download&gd=true

Comment: then after that of course valid access_token to the end

Comment: Just a guess ... try setting the access token as an HTTP header, rather than as a URL parameter

Comment: Ok , that seems to help .. but does not make any sense.. Thanks .. ( Should have tested that earlier , like you said)

Comment: Again, I'm blackbox guessing: when you call an API, you are hitting Google's new API "gateway", which is probably the layer that is unwrapping the access token from the URL and passing it on to the appropriate Google Service as a header (or some protobuf equivalent). When you are retrieving content, you are hitting a very different part of the Google infrastructure, and significantly, you are not going through the API gateway. So the rules may well be different. So the takeaway is, although some/all of the APIs support access tokens in the URL, it is better to use the authorization header.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a duplicate of [Unable to retrieve file content from google drive API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933790/unable-to-retrieve-file-content-from-google-drive-api?rq=1) which states that the access token for downloading content needs to be set as an HTTP header.