# Fetch file contents based on Google drive ID

Tags: android, google-drive-api

In my  project I have to backup and restore .db SQLite database to google drive. I looked through google documentation and demo project. I have problem with DRIVE ID.

that's my client:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) // required for App Folder sample
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
```

I've created  file as google showed:

```
public class CreateFileActivity extends BaseDemoActivity {

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    super.onConnected(connectionHint);
    // create new contents resource
    Drive.DriveApi.newContents(getGoogleApiClient())
            .setResultCallback(contentsCallback);
}

final private ResultCallback<ContentsResult> contentsCallback = new
        ResultCallback<ContentsResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(ContentsResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Error while trying to create new file contents");
            return;
        }

        MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                .setTitle("testFile.txt")
                .setMimeType("text/plain")
                .setStarred(true).build();
        // create a file on root folder
        Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient())
                .createFile(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet, result.getContents())
                .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
    }
};

final private ResultCallback<DriveFileResult> fileCallback = new
        ResultCallback<DriveFileResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveFileResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Error while trying to create the file");
            return;
        }
        showMessage("Created a file: " + result.getDriveFile().getDriveId());
        Log.e("misha", ""+result.getDriveFile().getDriveId() );
    }
};
}
```

Then retrieved it's drive ID with quering files by my filne name and printed it to Log :

```
public class QueryFilesActivity extends BaseDemoActivity {

private ListView mResultsListView;
private ResultsAdapter mResultsAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listfiles);
    mResultsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewResults);
    mResultsAdapter = new ResultsAdapter(this);
    mResultsListView.setAdapter(mResultsAdapter);
}

/**
 * Clears the result buffer to avoid memory leaks as soon
 * as the activity is no longer visible by the user.
 */
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mResultsAdapter.clear();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    super.onConnected(connectionHint);
    Query query = new Query.Builder()
            //.addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.MIME_TYPE, "text/plain"))
        .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, "testFile.txt"))
            .build();
    Drive.DriveApi.query(getGoogleApiClient(), query)
            .setResultCallback(metadataCallback);
}

final private ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult> metadataCallback = new
        ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(MetadataBufferResult result) {
        MetadataBuffer metaData = result.getMetadataBuffer();
        for (int i = 0 ; i <metaData.getCount(); i++){
            Log.e("misha", metaData.get(i).getDriveId().toString());
        }
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Problem while retrieving results");
            return;
        }
        mResultsAdapter.clear();
        mResultsAdapter.append(result.getMetadataBuffer());
    }
};
}
```

So, I have not\w my file's Drive Id XXXXXXXXXXZiUUxXM0lIUWFhV0pFV0hwSFVqWXhXRzgY9AXXXXXXXXXX. I guess it's correct ID. now when I want to get Contents of file. I get the following error

Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(getGoogleApiClient(), EXISTING_FILE_ID)
              .setResultCallback(idCallback);

> > Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?

I want to get contents of the file, also I want to change the contents and so on. But I stuck at retrieving file contents :( please help guys

Comment: You need to send `"Authorization: Bearer {your access token}"` header. Possible duplicate of [Unable to retrieve file content from google drive API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933790/unable-to-retrieve-file-content-from-google-drive-api)

Comment: Thanks, 
first. I should forget about such approuach and call get request ?
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/fileId

and where can I find "my access token"

When I run the web get request it says I need to authorize:
message: "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."